# Convert PNG with Content-Disposition attachment to Base64 or Buffer in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using a third-party API I receive a PNG attachement back from my request with:

Headers:

```
Content-Type: "image/png"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''Api-URL-2021-05-13T09-21-31-094_clipped_rev_1.png
```

And `data` that looks like this:

```
data: `�PNG\r\n...IHDR ........`
```

I can see the image displayed in postman and looks ok.

The issue is I want to save that image to an `S3 bucket` and convert this attachment to something I can save in `S3`.

Can I convert this `data` to something that I can save in my S3 bucket?

Here is my S3 function:

```
function saveFile(data: Buffer | Uint8Array | Blob | string | Readable) {
  const putParams = {
    Bucket: 'my-bucket',
    Key: 'test-file',
    Body: data,
  };
  s3.putObject(putParams, (putErr, putData) => {
    if (putErr) {
      console.error(putErr);
    } else {
      console.log(putData);
    }
  });
}
```

And `Body` can be any of these types: `Buffer | Uint8Array | Blob | string | Readable` according to `TypeScript`

Answer (score 0):

The data part of the response is the png file, looks correctly formatted from what you have shown, so no need to convert anything. I'm not too familiar with the S3 calls but that looks OK.  Use "blob" as the body type, i.e. binary.